# Comma in "нет-нет да найдутся"

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need a comma here before the second "да"?

> Да и среди нас нет-нет да найдутся неверующие в акцидентное
>   пресуществление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not need it.
First source I found is from [gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_487).
It says that it is an unbroken expression and provides a couple examples.

[Rozental's reference §96](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm#%D0%B7_03) (point 1, note в) states the same. However, both of the sources require you to have a *да и*, not just *да* in there.

I don't think I ever heard this expression without the *и*, but I also can't say it's mandatory. Maybe someone else can comment or edit me about the requirement of the *и*.

Comment: it is much rarer, but nevertheless valid and existent. For example
> Кабы вот не эта красная вывеска напротив, откуда нет-нет да вдруг слабо доносятся какие-то гудящие звуки

Comment: @shabunc: I think the reason there is no и in your example is that the following verb is imperfective. So putting an и there would be just wrong. In case of the OP's example, the verb is perfective so one really wants an и there, although I, too, can't say that its omission is ***wrong***, maybe simply unusual

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan - I could as well change the verb from perfective to imperfective in my example (найдутся -> наxодятся) and it would still sound ok to me. To me they all sound ok - regardless of the verb aspect or the presence of "и"

Answer (score 6):

запятая не ставится:

- перед сочетанием `да и`, имеющим соединительное значение (думал да и надумал)
- в выражении `нет-нет да и`
- в сочетании глаголов типа `взял да и приехал`.

[here is the link](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=238#pg238)

so you actually don't need comma here.